# Get each of the values from each of the objects present inside the array of objects

Tags: angularjs, arrays, object, foreach, key-value

I need to grab each of the values from each of the objects on click of the button.
For e.g., on click of the button 'Click Me' inside the first 'div.parent', should give me '$scope.color = ['Black', 'White'].

How do I get this?

Here's my code:

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.myData = [
 { 
   'car': 'Ford',
   'color': [{'primary':'Black'},{'secondary':'White'}],
   'number': '1, 2, 3',
   'model': 'Figo'     
 }, { 
   'car': 'Ford',
   'color': [{'primary':'Red'},{'secondary':'Black'}],
   'number': '4,5',
   'model': 'Endeavour'     
 },{ 
   'car': 'Jaguar',
   'color': [{'primary':'White'},{'secondary':'Red'}],
   'number': '6',
   'model': 'F-Type'     
 },
  ];
  
  $scope.getData = function(){
 $scope.color = angular.forEach(this.car.color, function(value, key){
  return $(this);
 });
 console.log($scope.color);
  };
}]);
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 10px;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button id="createData">Create Data</button>
  <div class="container">
 <div ng-repeat="car in myData" class="parent">
   <div>
  <label>Car:</label>
  <span>{{car.car}}</span>
   </div>
   <br />
   <div>
     <label>Model:</label>
  <span>{{car.model}}</span>
   </div>
   <br />
   <button ng-click="getData(obj)">Click Me!</button>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to push the correct values inside the colors array.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.myData = [
 { 
   'car': 'Ford',
   'color': [{'primary':'Black'},{'secondary':'White'}],
   'number': '1, 2, 3',
   'model': 'Figo'     
 }, { 
   'car': 'Ford',
   'color': [{'primary':'Red'},{'secondary':'Black'}],
   'number': '4,5',
   'model': 'Endeavour'     
 },{ 
   'car': 'Jaguar',
   'color': [{'primary':'White'},{'secondary':'Red'}],
   'number': '6',
   'model': 'F-Type'     
 },
  ];
  
  $scope.getData = function(obj){
   $scope.color =[]; 
        $scope.color.push(obj[0].primary);
        $scope.color.push(obj[1].secondary);
 console.log($scope.color);
  };
}]);
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 10px;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button id="createData">Create Data</button>
  <div class="container">
 <div ng-repeat="car in myData" class="parent">
   <div>
  <label>Car:</label>
  <span>{{car.car}}</span>
   </div>
   <br />
   <div>
     <label>Model:</label>
  <span>{{car.model}}</span>
   </div>
   <br />
   <button ng-click="getData(car.color)">Click Me!</button>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to do it by iterating over my array of objects as there's no definite number of objects.

Comment: But in ng-repeat, only one instance will be passed as a functional parameter and that could be used to store the colors of the corresponding car instance

Comment: You are clicking each line item and storing the color corresponding to that line item. What exactly is the requirement?

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.myData = [
 { 
   'car': 'Ford',
   'color': [{'primary':'Black'},{'secondary':'White'}],
   'number': '1, 2, 3',
   'model': 'Figo'     
 }, { 
   'car': 'Ford',
   'color': [{'primary':'Red'},{'secondary':'Black'}],
   'number': '4,5',
   'model': 'Endeavour'     
 },{ 
   'car': 'Jaguar',
   'color': [{'primary':'White'},{'secondary':'Red'}],
   'number': '6',
   'model': 'F-Type'     
 },
  ];
  
  $scope.getData = function(colorObj){
 //$scope.color = angular.forEach(this.car.color, function(value, key){
 // return $(this);
 //});
  
 console.log("color Array : ",colorObj);
    console.log("selected colors: ",colorObj[0].primary, ' ',colorObj[1].secondary);
  };
}]);
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 10px;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button id="createData">Create Data</button>
  <div class="container">
 <div ng-repeat="car in myData" class="parent">
   <div>
  <label>Car:</label>
  <span>{{car.car}}</span>
   </div>
   <br />
   <div>
     <label>Model:</label>
  <span>{{car.model}}</span>
   </div>
   <br />
   <button ng-click="getData(car.color)">Click Me!</button>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You will get the color array. Using `colorObj[0].primary`  you can access the color value.